# Is the electroweak gauge group a semidirect product?

Tags: standard-model, gauge-theory, group-theory, topology, electroweak

In the typical treatment of electroweak theory, the gauge group is $G = \mathrm{SU}(2)_I \times \mathrm{U}(1)_Y$. This group is broken by the Higgs mechanism, while the combination of generators $Q = I_3 + Y$ generates an unbroken $\mathrm{U}(1)_Q$ subgroup.

I've wondered whether it is possible to represent the gauge group in a way that the embedding of $\mathrm{U}(1)_Q$ is obvious. The Lie bracket of $I_1$, $I_2$, $I_3$ and $Q$ seems to have the structure of a semidirect product.

Is it correct to say that the gauge group is a semidirect product $G \cong \mathrm{SU}(2)_I \rtimes \mathrm{U}(1)_Q$?

Comment: [Linked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3378416/describing-the-lie-algebra-structure-of-a-semi-direct-product-of-lie-groups).

Comment: Might adduce the commutator $[Q,I_{\pm}]=\pm I_{\pm}$ at the end of your middle paragraph, and skip "seems"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Note that the group monomorphism $$U(1)_Q\quad \stackrel{i}{\hookrightarrow}\quad G~:=~ N\times U(1)_Y, \qquad N~:=~SU(2)_I,$$ depends on the [Weinberg angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle), cf. e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/239276/2451). Here the subscript $I=T$ denotes [weak isospin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_isospin), the subscript $Y$ denotes [weak hypercharge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_hypercharge), and the subscript $Q$ denotes [electric charge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge). Let $i_1=\pi_1\circ i$ and $i_2=\pi_2\circ i$ denote the projection to 1st and 2nd group, respectively.
2. We can use the embedding $i$ to define a [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) $N\rtimes U(1)_Q$ with elements $$\begin{align}
   N\rtimes U(1)_Q~\ni~(g,h)~:=~&(gi_1(h),i_2(h))~\in~N\times U(1)_Y,\cr
   (g_1,h_1)\bullet(g_2,h_2)~=~&\left(g_1i_1(h_1)g_2i_1(h_1^{-1}),h_1h_2\right).\end{align}$$
   Returning to OP's title question, it is less clear whether this constitutes a bijection between Lie groups
   $$N\rtimes U(1)_Q\quad\to \quad N\times U(1)_Y~=:~G,$$
   although they are certainly isomorphic at the Lie algebra level.