# Charge of a field under the action of a group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra

What does it mean for a field (say, $\phi$) to have a charge (say, $Q$) under the action of a group (say, $U(1)$)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It means that

1. the [charge operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charge_%28physics%29) $Q$ is a [Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) generator for some [Lie group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group) $G$.
2. the field $\phi\in V$ takes values/transform in a [representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_of_a_Lie_group) $V$ of the Lie group. (Note that any Lie group representation $V$ is also [Lie algebra  representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra_representation) of the corresponding Lie algebra.)
3. the charge operator $\rho(Q)$ in the representation $\rho: G \to GL(V)$ is proportional to the identity. The proportionality factor/eigenvalue is the actual charge of the field.

To see an example of this, say the (strong) $u(1)$ hypercharge $Y$, see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16567/2451).