# Facts About Quarks Electric Charge

Tags: particle-physics, charge, quarks

Quarks have the unusual characteristic of having a fractional electric charge.
here there is a new model that suggests maybe an up Quark has no electric charge and infact down Quark has electric charge of (+1,-1), through weak interaction between Up Quark and W$^{\pm}$

$$u^{0}+W^{+}\to d^{+},$$
$$u^{0}+W^{-}\to d^{-},$$

sounds like this idea consisted with neutron decay.
$$n^{0}\to p^{+}+W^{-},$$
$$u^{0}d^{-}d^{+}\to u^{0}u^{0}d^{+}+W^{-}.$$

Reference: http://meetings.aps.org/Meeting/OSS13/Event/195666

Comment: That's not a reference. This guy cannot even be found on Inspire.

Comment: This doesn't look like a question...

Comment: But what's your question after all? You want to have any explanation about this? Always make your questions very explicit so that we know what is being really asked.

Comment: Possible duplicate also asking about Ahmad Reza Estakhr's quark model: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/37998/2451

Comment: The cross-section for Drell-Yan goes by the $\text{number of colors} \times \sum_\text{accessible mass}  \text{squared quark charges}$. It is consistent the standard model a multiple experiments (including one I helped build my first year of experimental work). See https://www.google.com/search?q=pion+production+quark+charges .

Comment: The answer from Mitchell Porter in the -claimed- duplicate question tells most of the history: Han-Nambu solutions.

Answer (score -2):

This idea that probabilities is associated with unknown parameters is true!, so Quarks fractional electric charge is not accurate value. it is the most probable value

Comment: Completely incorrect. The quark charges can be (and have been) measured.

Comment: Related post: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/60356/2451